# How to write type hints for an iterable abstract base class?

Tags: python, abstract-class, type-hinting

I need to write an abstract base class for classes that:

- derive from an existing class, `SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom` (this is why I can't use a `Protocol`, I need this to be an abstract base class),
- implement the `Iterable` interface,
- contain objects of a specific type, `Element` (i.e. if we iterate over an instance, we get objects of type `Element`).

I tried to add a type hint to `__iter__` in the abstract base class:

```py
import abc
import collections.abc
import typing

class Element:
    pass

class SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom:
    pass

class BaseIterableClass(
    abc.ABC,
    collections.abc.Iterable,
    SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom,
):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self) -> typing.Iterator[Element]:
        ...

class A(BaseIterableClass):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return "some string that isn't an Element"

a = A()
a_it = iter(a)
a_el = next(a)
```

But `mypy` doesn't detect any errors here, even though `a` is a `BaseIterableClass` instance that contains `str`s instead of `Element`s. I'm assuming that `__iter__` is subject to name mangling, which means that the type hint is ignored.

How can I type hint `BaseIterableClass` so that deriving from it with an `__iter__` function that iterates over something else than `Element` causes a typing error?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. In which line are you expecting `mypy` to detect a type error? In the `__next__` return statement? And another question: Are you _sure_ you need that base class to implement the `Iterable` interface and not the `Iterator` interface?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg The base class defines an interface: an `Iterable` object that contains `Element`s. The child class breaks this interface by containing `str`s instead. I expect this to be a typing error, since one can then create a `BaseIterableClass` instance that contains `str`, which goes against the declared API of `BaseIterableClass`.

Comment: There is no contract here that would have any static type checker expect any particular return type from `A.__next__`. You need to annotate the return type for the `A.__next__` method with `-> Element` for the code to cause a `mypy` error. Even if you specified the `A.__iter__` return type to be `Iterator[Element]` that still doesn't mean that `A.__next__` returns `Element` types. Your `A.__iter__` _could theoretically_ return a totally unrelated iterator object over `Element`, whereas the `A.__next__` method on that class could return something else.

Answer (score 2):

Running `mypy` in `--strict` mode actually tells you everything you need.

### 1) Incomplete `Iterable`

```
:13: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Iterable"  [type-arg]
```

Since `Iterable` is generic and [parameterized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias) with one type variable, you should subclass it accordingly, i.e.

```py
...
T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound="Element")
...
class BaseIterableClass(
    abc.ABC,
    collections.abc.Iterable[T],
    SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom,
):
```

### 2) Now we get a new error

```
:17: error: Return type "Iterator[Element]" of "__iter__" incompatible with return type "Iterator[T]" in supertype "Iterable"  [override]
```

Easily solvable:

```py
...
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self) -> typing.Iterator[T]:
```

### 3) Now that we made `BaseIterableClass` properly generic...

```
:20: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "BaseIterableClass"  [type-arg]
```

Here we can specify `Element`:

```py
class A(BaseIterableClass[Element]):
...
```

### 4) Missing return types

```
:21: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
:24: error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
```

Since we are defining the methods `__iter__` and `__next__` for `A`, we need to annotate them properly:

```py
...
    def __iter__(self) -> collections.abc.Iterator[Element]:
...
    def __next__(self) -> Element:
```

### 5) Wrong return value

Now that we annotated the `__next__` return type, `mypy` picks up that `"some string that isn't an Element"` is not, in fact, an instance of `Element`.

```
:25: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "Element")  [return-value]
```

### Fully annotated code

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound="Element")


class Element:
    pass


class SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom:
    pass


class BaseIterableClass(
    ABC,
    Iterable[T],
    SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom,
):
    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        ...


class A(BaseIterableClass[Element]):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Element]:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> Element:
        return "some string that isn't an Element"  # error
        # return Element()
```

---

### Fixed type argument

If you don't want `BaseIterableClass` to be generic, you can change steps **1)-3)** and specify the type argument for all subclasses. Then you don't need to pass a type argument for `A`. The code would then look like so:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator


class Element:
    pass


class SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom:
    pass


class BaseIterableClass(
    ABC,
    Iterable[Element],
    SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom,
):
    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Element]:
        ...


class A(BaseIterableClass):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Element]:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> Element:
        return "some string that isn't an Element"  # error
        # return Element()
```

---

### Maybe `Iterator` instead?

Finally, it seems that you actually want the `Iterator` interface, since you are defining the `__next__` method on your subclass `A`. In that case, you don't need to define `__iter__` at all. `Iterator` inherits from `Iterable` and automatically gets `__iter__` mixed in, when you inherit from it and implement `__next__`. (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes))

Also, since the `Iterator` base class is abstract already, you don't need to include `__next__` as an abstract method.

Then the (generic version of the) code would look like this:

```py
from abc import ABC
from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound="Element")


class Element:
    pass


class SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom:
    pass


class BaseIteratorClass(
    ABC,
    Iterator[T],
    SomeClassIHaveToDeriveFrom,
):
    pass


class A(BaseIteratorClass[Element]):
    def __next__(self) -> Element:
        return "some string that isn't an Element"  # error
        # return Element()
```

Both `iter(A())` and `next(A())` work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I need this class to be `Iterable`, but it simplifies the implementation if the class is its own `Iterator`.

Comment: Actually I'm confused: in `A`, you explicitly typed `def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Element]`. Does that mean that the return type can't be inherited from `BaseIteratorClass`, and that a child class can always redefine the return type arbitrarily? I expected the child class to get a typing error if it didn't follow the parent class' interface.

Comment: @Arno Since Python is dynamically typed, you _can_ always return any type whatsoever. But static type checkers like `mypy` will give you an error, if you override the subclass' method signature in a way that is not compatible with the superclass. But you you have to annotate it _somehow_, otherwise the static type checker will complain that the annotation is missing. Unless you are using subtypes in the overridden method, this means you simply have to repeat the annotations already present on the superclass' method. Does that make sense?